# Is there a way to clear a MUI TextField Input from the form.restart() method in React-Final-Form and capture the event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-final-form

The form.restart() in my reset button resets all fields states and values as per my understanding of this [Final-Form](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#restart).
The method fires and resets all fields in my form and I can capture the event in the autocomplete, but I am unable to capture the *clear* event in the textfield - I have a state (not related to the value of the field) I need tor reset.

My form reset button

```js
<Button
  type={"button"}
  disabled={submitting || pristine}
  variant={"outlined"}
  onClick={() => {
    form.getRegisteredFields().forEach((field) => form.resetFieldState(field));
    form.restart();
    if (clearActionHandler) {
      clearActionHandler();
    }
    setFormSubmittedOnce(false);
  }}
>
  Clear
</Button>;
```

My textfieldadapter

```js
const [shrink, setShrink] = useState < boolean > false;
const countCharacters: (
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
) => boolean = (e) => {
  setCount(e.target.value.length);
  return maxCharacterCount === 0 || e.target.value.length < maxCharacterCount;
};

return (
  <TextField
    {...input}
    {...rest}
    onChange={(e) => {
      if (countCharacters(e)) {
        input.onChange(e);
      }
    }}
    value={input.value}
    onBlur={(e) => {
      !input.value && input.onBlur(e);
      !input.value && setShrink(false);
    }}
    error={meta.error && meta.touched}
    helperText={
      meta.touched ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          {maxCharacterCount > 0 ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography variant={"body1"} textAlign={"end"}>
                {count}/{maxCharacterCount}
              </Typography>
              <br />
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : null}{" "}
          {meta.error}
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : maxCharacterCount > 0 ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Typography variant={"body1"} textAlign={"end"}>
            {count}/{maxCharacterCount}
          </Typography>
          <br />
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        ""
      )
    }
    placeholder={placeholder}
    fullWidth={true}
    margin={"dense"}
    multiline={multiline > 1}
    rows={multiline}
    inputProps={inputProps}
    InputProps={{
      startAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position={"start"} sx={{ width: "24px" }}>
          {startAdornment}
        </InputAdornment>
      ),
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: shrink,
    }}
    onFocus={() => setShrink(true)}
    sx={{
      "& .MuiInputLabel-root:not(.MuiInputLabel-shrink)": {
        transform: "translate(50px, 17px)",
      },
    }}
  />
);
```

Versions of packages:
"@mui/material": "^5.11.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-final-form": "^6.5.9"

---

I have tried to capture the onChange event with bluring all elements before the reset method is called, that doesn't call the textfield onblur method. I am just not sure how to clear it away.

Comment: Unless my understanding is wrong, when you clear the data, no event is really fired anywhere -- it's just setting the `value` back to its initial value. Changing the value of a field programmatically (not via a user typing) won't trigger an event. Are you saying that when this happens, this text field doesn't actually clear its value? Can you also let me know what the `initialValue` is for this particular field? It makes me wonder if the initial value is null/undefined. It should be empty string, or the text field might flip back to uncontrolled mode which may explain it (this is a long shot).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the field in question has an entry in `initialValues` and that that entry is initialised to an empty string. This is a long shot, so take everything I say as theory, but it looks like what would happen if the initial value was not defined or was explicitly set to `undefined`.

That would mean when you reset the form, the `value` prop of the `TextField` would be set to `undefined`. This is not a valid controlled value of a `TextField`, so the behavior of MUI could well be to switch to uncontrolled mode, where the value is kept internally and not actually controlled by the `value` prop any more. It depends on the library what happens next as this is generally unexpected and leads to non-deterministic behavior, but it's likely that MUI just keeps the previous controlled value around internally, or it's sitting in a transient DOM state on the element itself since `value` is judged to be no longer the source of truth and so it was never written to the actual DOM element. When the user types again, `onChange` would be called, the state in your form set to a string, and it would become controlled again. Base react `<input>` gives warnings in the console when you transition like this but MUI might not.

This might explain why it does not capture the transition to the original form state.

Note `null` is usually not allowed either [but there's some final form magic that protects you from that one.](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#allownull)

I verified MUI does this on a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-sofy2f?file=/src/index.js) (excuse the old class style I just used an old `TextField` sandbox to build on). If my long shot is correct, the problem is more related to a core issue between your state consistency and the mui lib and less about final form.

The fix would be to make sure the field has an entry in `initialValues` set to a string. You could optionally put in guards to check for `undefined` and use `''` instead when that's the case.

Take note that `''` is actually still falsey so `!input.value` would evaluate to true when it's empty string still. Not sure you care, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Just a note that it could be worth using a library to do these bindings where these caveats have probably been ironed out https://github.com/lookfirst/mui-rff